# Herencia de clases con polimorfismo

Tags: c++, clase, herencia, polimorfismo

He creado una clase base persona y dos clases derivadas, alumno y profesor.

Tengo un problema con el constructor de la clase derivada profesor y me sale el siguiente error.

```
D:\C++\HerenciaPersonas\profe.cpp|3|undefined reference to `vtable for profe'|
```

Lo raro es que con la otra clase derivada alumno no me sale ningun problema y me compilaba bien antes de incluir la nueva clase derivada profesor.

Por aqui os dejo todos los archivos de las tres clases

Clase base:

```
#ifndef PERSONA_H
#define PERSONA_H
class persona
{
    public:
        virtual void mostrar() = 0;
        virtual void nota() = 0;
};
#endif // PERSONA_H
```

La clase base no tiene ningun metodo implementado, ya que unicamente es una plantilla para las otras clases.

Clase alumno:

```
#ifndef ALUMNO_H
#define ALUMNO_H
#include "persona.h"
#include <iostream>
class alumno : public persona
{
    public:
        alumno(int nota,std::string nombre);
        alumno();
        void mostrar();
        void nota();
    private:
        int notas;
        std::string nombre;
};
#endif // ALUMNO_H
```

Implementacion:

```
#include "alumno.h"
#include "persona.h"
alumno::alumno(int nota,std::string nombre) :notas(nota),nombre(nombre)
{
}
alumno::alumno():notas(0),nombre("")
{
}
void alumno::mostrar()
{
    std::cout<<"Es tipo alumno";
}

void alumno::nota()
{
    std::cout<<"Su nota es "<<notas;
}
```

Clase profesor(donde me da el error)

```
#ifndef PROFE_H
#define PROFE_H
#include "persona.h"
#include <iostream>
class profe: public persona
{
    public:
        profe();
        profe(std::string n, int h);
        virtual ~profe();
        virtual void nota();
        virtual void mostrar();
    private:
        std::string nombre;
        int horas;
};
#endif // PROFE_H
```

Archivo implementacion:

```
#include "profe.h"
#include "persona.h"
profe::profe() : nombre(""),horas(0)
{
}
profe::profe(std::string n, int h) : nombre(n),horas(h)
{
}
void profe::mostrar()
{
    std::cout<<"Es profesor";
}
void profe::nota()
{
    std::cout<<"No tiene nota, es un profesor";
}
```

Se agradece cualquier tipo de ayuda o de sugerencia, un saludo muchas gracias.

Comment: @Trauma si te refieres al archivo main, esta vacio, unicamente el return 0;

Comment: ya me compila quitando el destructor, muchas gracias por la ayuda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te faltó implementar el destructor de la clase `profe`.

---

Por cierto, a menos que quieras seguir heredando la clase y usar polimorfismo, no necesitas `virtual` en la siguientes funciones:

```
virtual ~profe();
virtual void nota();
virtual void mostrar();
```