# Polimorfismo en clases con herencia

Tags: c++, clase, herencia, polimorfismo

He creado una clase base llamada persona y dos clases derivadas, alumno y profesor y solo tienen tres metodos, mostrar, que dice de que clase es el objeto, nota, que es casi lo mismo que la anterior, y convertir, que mi objetivo es que convierta un profesor en alumno y viceversa, pero cuando en el main intento convertir un objeto de una clase a otra, este se mantiene en la clase inicial.

Por aqui os dejo todos los archivos:

Clase base(no tiene implementacion, solo plantilla)

```
#ifndef PERSONA_H
#define PERSONA_H
class persona
{
    public:

        virtual void mostrar() = 0;
        virtual void nota() = 0;
        virtual persona& convertir(int a) = 0;
};
#endif // PERSONA_H
```

Clase alumno:

```
#ifndef ALUMNO_H
#define ALUMNO_H
#include "persona.h"
#include <iostream>
class alumno : public persona
{
    public:
        alumno(int nota,std::string nombre);
        alumno();
        virtual void mostrar();
        void nota();
        virtual persona& convertir(int a);
    private:
        int notas;
        std::string nombre;
};
#endif // ALUMNO_H
```

Implementacion:

```
#include "alumno.h"
#include "persona.h"
#include "profe.h"
alumno::alumno(int nota,std::string nombre) :notas(nota),nombre(nombre)
{
}
alumno::alumno():notas(0),nombre("")
{
}
void alumno::mostrar()
{
    std::cout<<"Es tipo alumno";
}
void alumno::nota()
{
    std::cout<<"Su nota es "<<notas;
}
persona& alumno::convertir(int a)
{
    persona* p = new profe(nombre,a);
    return *p;
}
```

Clase profe:

```
#ifndef PROFE_H
#define PROFE_H
#include "persona.h"
#include <iostream>
class profe: public persona
{
    public:
        profe(std::string n, int h);

        virtual void nota();
        virtual void mostrar();
        virtual persona& convertir(int a);
    private:
        std::string nombre;
        int horas;
};
#endif // PROFE_H
```

Implementacion:

```
#include "profe.h"
#include "persona.h"
#include "alumno.h"
profe::profe(std::string n, int h) : nombre(n),horas(h)
{

}
void profe::mostrar()
{
    std::cout<<"Es profesor";
}
void profe::nota()
{
    std::cout<<"No tiene nota, es un profesor";
}
persona& profe::convertir(int a)
{
    persona* p = new alumno(a,nombre);
    return *p;
}
```

Archivo main donde intento convertir p1, que es inicialmente de tipo profe a tipo alumno:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "persona.h"
#include "alumno.h"
#include "profe.h"
#include <vector>

int main()
{

    persona* p1 = new profe("Paco",5);
    p1->convertir(3);
    p1->mostrar();
    return 0;
}
```

Se agradece cualquier ayuda o sugerencia. Muchas gracias.

Comment: Quizá aún no lo hayas visto. Destaco la segunda parte de [la respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/574575/169744) que te acabo de dejar en otra pregunta. Probablemente no necesites marcar las funciones de las clases derivadas con `virtual`.

Comment: lo que he hecho a sido eliminar el destructor de la cabecera de la clase, con respecto a esta pregunta, creo que ya la he solucionado, ya que la clase convertir devuelve un objeto de la clase contraria al original pero no modifica el objeto original por lo que si p1 era profe seguira siendo profe, gracias de todas formas por la ayuda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es muy similar en ambos casos.

Te invito a que revises la función `convertir` de cualquiera de las dos clases:

```
persona& profe::convertir(int a)
{
    persona* p = new alumno(a,nombre);
    return *p;
}
```

La función crea un objeto de la clase correspondiente en el heap y devuelve una referencia a este.

Como en el `main` estás usando punteros sugiero que cambies el tipo de retorno a un puntero también:

```
persona* profe::convertir(int a)
{
    return new alumno(a,nombre);
}
```

Igualmente hay algo que está faltando en la función `main`. Es que la variable `p1` no va a cambiar a menos que la asignes:

```
p1 = p1->convertir(3);
```

---

Por cierto, al trabajar con memoria dinámica deberías liberar la cuando termines de trabajar con ella. Mediante `delete`.

Por ejemplo en el `main` deberías hacerlo así:

```
persona* tmp = p1->convertir(3);
delete p1;
p1 = tmp;
...
delete p1;
```

Nota que guardo el retorno en una variable temporal porque sino quedaría memoria sin liberar.